# Session value in delete statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write a code through which user can deactivate his account after login.
In Login page i have created a session and get it in page load method of deactivate account page.
Here is my delete query but is is not working with session value.

```
String SQLQuery = "DELETE FROM SignUp Where Password=\'" + txtPassword.Text + "\' AND EmailAddress= \'" + Session["email"]+ "\'";
```

Comment: This query raises many, many red flags.  First, SQL injection, as others have said.  Use parameters.  Second, deleting an account based upon an un-hashed password?  I don't know much about your app, but please read up on "password hashing" and "sql injection" before going much further!

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure `session["email"]` is set before you use in query and it in not *null* and you getting value in it. Also use parameters to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can read this [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) how to make SQL query with parameters.

```
String SQLQuery = "DELETE FROM SignUp Where Password=\'" + txtPassword.Text + "\' AND EmailAddress= \'" + Session["email"].ToString() + "\'";
```

Comment: Not true about ToString. ToString() is automatically executed when you use a non-string object in a string expression like this. What else is added to the sql query?

Answer (score 0):

you miss "ToString()" method after session["email"]

like this

```
session["email"].ToString()
```

It is recommended to check the session is available before using it

```
if(Session["email"] != null)
{
String SQLQuery = "DELETE FROM SignUp Where Password=\'" + txtPassword.Text + "\' AND EmailAddress= \'" + Session["email"].Tostring() + "\'";
}
else
{
   //session timeout
}
```

One more thing, your sql code will expose you to sqlinjection ..
It is recommended you to use Parameterize to execute sql query to avoid sql injection . like this

```
if(Session["email"] != null)
    {
string password =  txtPassword.Text;
string email = Session["email"].Tostring();


    String SQLQuery = "DELETE FROM SignUp Where Password=@pass AND EmailAddress=@email";
SqlCommand dbComm = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery , new SqlConnection() );
dbComm.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password ;
dbComm.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email  ;

//execute sql
    }
    else
    {
       //session timeout
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this method when i debugged my code string pass has value but string email has nothing.I have used Login control whose user name value is equal to session value  Session["email"] = Login1.UserName;
This query is giving me error must declare scalar variable pass.

Comment: if (Session["email"] != null) condtion is true but string email contains nothing

Comment: Not true about ToString. ToString() is automatically executed when you use a non-string object in a string expression like this. What else is added to the sql query?